# poster image not displaying with add_movie() in python-pptx

Tags: powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to insert some sound files into a presentation, and the sound file seems to save fine, but the display image is always the default play button logo. Is there something wrong with my code, or is it another issue. I am currently working in a linux environment, if that makes any difference. I have tried with both mp4 and mp3 and the image issue is the same. The small play bar also seems not to appear although the sound file is in the presentation.

```py
    from pptx import Presentation
    from pptx.util import Inches
    
    prs = Presentation()
    title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
    
    prs.slides[0].shapes.add_movie("sample2.mp3", 
                               left = Inches(1), top = Inches(1), width = Inches(1), height = Inches(1), 
                               poster_frame_image = "cat.jpeg"
                               )
    
    prs.save('sound_image.pptx')
```

Comment: Movies have poster frames; sounds do not, so PPT can't display a poster frame for sound files.

Comment: I have been able to do it in the past on a windows environnment. Also it has been noted by others that this is possible with this method. See: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/502

Comment: Also, the issue persists when uuploading an .mp4 version of the file.

Comment: When you say the image doesn't appear, do you mean it doesn't in LibreOffice? Or have you tried it in PowerPoint? Also, try inserting `cat.jpeg` using `.add_picture()` just to rule out a problem with the file or path.

Comment: I've checked the path like you said, no issues there. I don't have a windows environment right now so I've been using libre office and the online powerpoint program. I'm getting a new computer in a couple weeks so I will be able to test stuff out in actual PowerPoint then.

Comment: Ok so I've tried again, and it works well with an actual video instead of audio converted to mp4, in the online powerpoint, no idea why. I suspect that the issue is with it being an audio file, more than my OS but I'm not sure. For now I see two possibilities, first might be to convert all my current mp3's to mp4's using the poster frame for every frame in the video, which would probably work but is a bit of effort. Second is to make a fork of python-pptx that has a function similar to add_movie() that can handle the audio files better. Not sure which would be easier.

Comment: I don't understand where you expect a poster frame to come from when you start with an audio file, converted to movie format or not.  But once you have a movie file, PPT has a SetDisplayPictureFromFile method that allows you to override the default poster frame in the movie file. Or in this case, assign one when none exists.

Comment: For what I'm using the audio file will almost always accompany an image, so I could use that image to make the frames in the video. I don't think it's a very practical solution though in all honesty, just looking for options. Looking at it more closely the mp3 file made with add_movie() seems to not register properly in the slide. When I insert an mp3 through the program it registers as an audio component and gives different options like to play on click and what not. With the inserted one it registers simply as 'shape' and gives none of those options.

Comment: An MP3 inserted normally behaves like an audio component because it *is* one. The fact that it may have been extracted from a movie isn't relevant; it's the sound portion of the movie with all the video bits thrown in the trash. If you want to display an image that the user can click to play a sound, try inserting the desired picture then adding an action setting to have it play the sound file. (Possible drawback: that'll create a link to the sound file, meaning that the sound file and the PPTX must be kept together for this to work)

Comment: The main curiosity is that the mp3 inserted with add_movie() *aren't* recognized as audio components by powerpoint. My issue isn't with powerpoint really. I am trying to use python-pptx to insert a sound file, but there isn't a function to do that specifically. add_movie() is a function in that library designed to insert a video file, but some users have had success inserting sound files with it anyway. I want to be able to insert thousands+ of sound clips, and using python-pptx would be ideal if I can get it to work.

Comment: I'm looking into using hyperlinks as you suggested since that might work as well. I'm a little nervous about using hyperlink to open a file since it opens some vulnerability to the user if the referenced file was tampered with, switched etc.

Comment: It sounds as though there's some kind of disconnect between PPT/its object model and the way add_movie is implemented. As a workaround, what happens if you have a movie file that's nothing but a single image in the video track plus the audio track you want to insert?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily add any sound files to presentations and set poster images for them by using [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/) as shown below:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides

presentation_path = "example.pptx"
audio_path = "sample2.mp3"
image_path = "cat.jpeg"

with slides.Presentation() as presentation:

    slide = presentation.slides[0]

    # Add an audio frame to the slide with a specified position and size.
    with open(audio_path, 'rb') as audio_stream:
        audio_frame = slide.shapes.add_audio_frame_embedded(150, 100, 50, 50, audio_stream)

    # Add the image to presentation resources.
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_stream:
        audio_image = presentation.images.add_image(image_stream)

    # Set the image as the audio poster.
    audio_frame.picture_format.picture.image = audio_image

    presentation.save(presentation_path, slides.export.SaveFormat.PPTX)
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.